# How can i divide each row of a vector with its next row value in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

Suppose i have the vector `a=[1;2;2]` i want to create the vector `b=[1/2;1;2]` deviding each value of the `ith` row of a with the `ith+1` value, the last value can't be divided with anything so i let like it is. I made a simple code, but i get the following error message: "Index exceeds matrix dimensions", so i need your help. Example code

```
a=rand(3,1);  
for i=1:length(a)
   b(i)=a(i)/a(i+1)
end
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try :

```
b=a./[a(2:end);1];
```

Not pretty but it works.

The error message "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" comes from your try to reference a(i+1) when i=length(a) since this element does not exist.

Comment: Or `a(1:end-1)./a(2:end)`. Pretty or not, vectorized solutions are generally better.